# Cant get desired results for multiple sort criteria in a view

Tags: views

I have created a points table for a race event and would like to sort the results in a specific order.

I am working with a table view that contains 3 sort criteria:

1. the race event (working fine done via table settings)
2. class of a car A, B , C and
3. the points each driver receives.

I would like the order to be A then points B then points C then points regardless of what class has the highest points.

### Problem:

If for example a C class car has points higher than any B class car then the stacking order is ACB. As soon as any B class car gets higher points than the C class car then the order is ABC (how I would like it). This can be seen in class A where Driver 2 has the lowest points of all.

I have tried re arranging the sort order but that does nothing.

[image: Screen shot of the problem]

Comment: Have you set up group by in views?

Comment: Hi Molot, Thank you for the quick reply. Yes in the table settings I have grouped by Event then by Class

Comment: I think, the issue is that you have grouped the element. Could you share your require output, so we can suggest you alternative?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by require output. I am new to drupal (8 weeks)

Comment: Please try this after removing grouping.

Comment: Hi Jayendra, If the grouping is removed I loose the group by event and by class. What remains is a single table ordered by points highest to lowest.

Comment: I will look into this and if I found I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Can i suggest removing the grouping and getting the single table to display as you would like it and then once you have done that apply the grouping. It sounds as if youre sorting by points not by car class - can you change the sort to car class then add the group.

Or **group** by event and then **sort** by car class and points.

Comment: I removed all the grouping other than event. I added sort by car class and it sorted by car class. As soon as points are introduced into the sort criteria it overrides the car class and sorts by points. Numbers appear to take precedence over letters

Comment: in your view can you rearrange the sort so that the sort by car class is on top of the sort by points? (in the sort box click on the arrow on the add button and it should give you a rearrange option.)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and it made no difference. As soon as points are introduced into the sort, it takes precedence.

Comment: as noted in this [article](https://drupal.org/node/54459) do you have any default sorts set?

Comment: Thank you Craicerjack I added a relationship to the vocabulary and added weight to the vocabulary as mentioned in the article. Added the relationship to the Car class in the sort criteria and now I have grouped  class A B C then points in the class..... Many Thanks to all for the help Best Regards Alan

Comment: Glad that you got it sorted. And glad that I could help

Answer (score -1):

You can use [hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module which has good option for customizing the hierarchical points

Comment: Hi Manu kumar, Thank you for the quick reply. I will have a look at this

Comment: I think, Hierarchical select will not use in this condition. Its only sort the select box, not view result.